# Which Base items are available without DLC or marketplace purchase?

Tags: dc-universe-online

I want to farm for Base items, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm willing to slog through side missions, beat up mobs of AI for drops, or hoard cash for a specific vendor. I'd like to avoid paying any real money, either for the items themselves, or for DLC packs that open missions where the items are available, etc (I've already spent enough real money on other things in the game...for now).

There have been multiple DLC additions to *DCUO* relating to Bases/Lairs, and a lot of the Base items that exist seem to come from areas that aren't available immediately, [according to this thread](https://forums.daybreakgames.com/dcuo/index.php?threads/base-loot-that-give-base-feats-drop-locations.443/).

I'm not sure how complete that list is (I'm guessing not very), it's just one of the only sources I could find. But, it's hard to tell just by the location of the item drop whether or not the location is in a DLC episode area, an On-Duty scenario, or maybe just a mission-specific area I haven't reached. I don't want to go looking for items I'm not going to find, so I'm wondering what's even available for me, playing without a membership or DLC mission purchases.

**What Base customization items (themed bundles or individual items) are available for purchase with in-game currency, in non-DLC areas? Are there any scripted Base item drops in non-DLC areas?**

Comment: I would imagine this to be a relatively short list, and I don't need every single item, but if I'm off base and this is a huge list question I will gladly edit / close.

Comment: I also added "scripted" in the last part because if an item is only available via truly random drop, it would be cool to know about but impossible to farm for, so those aren't necessary to list IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items are available with in-game currency via the Broker.  If you are a Premium player, they are also available for trade.  They can also be traded via League banks.

Items drop throughout the game, but I assume you're referring to the base items for the Base feats.  There is one that is lockbox-only: all the items in the Stuffed feat.  The rest can be farmed elsewhere, but it is unlikely that you will find a complete set by farming only free areas.  As you can see when new content comes out, the base items in loot tables frequently change.  It may be that only content-related items change, though, while older base items remain un-rotated.

Comment: Rusty Shackleford. Nice.

Comment: What makes you think you know who I am?  Who do you work for?  XD